# Regex for Numbers, some special characters and NULL

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create a regex which would allow

`0-9`

`.`

`>`

`<`

`%`

`,`

`-`

`NULL`

so I wrote a regex like `^[0-9.><%,-NULL]*$`

This matches NULL but should not match when user only enters `N`. So I did `^[0-9.&gt;&lt;%,-(NULL)]*$` but I do

```
string pattern = "^[0-9.&gt;&lt;%,-(NULL)]*$";
Regex.Match("N", pattern).Success;
```

this throws Argument exception and says

```
`parsing "^[0-9.><%,-(NULL)]*$" - [x-y] range in reverse order.
```

So what should be the correct Regex?

Comment: Is `NULLNULLNULL` a string that should be matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the expression you need looks similar to this:

```
"^([-0-9.><%,]|NULL)*$"
```

This will match zero or more occurrences of any of the characters in the character set (inside the square brackets) and instances of `NULL`.

---

Making `NULL` part of your character set will also match the `N`, `U` and `L` characters separately. Attempting to group using `(NULL)` will not have the desired effect, but will additionally make the character set also match the opening and closing parentheses.

The error you mention (`[x-y] range in reverse order`) is caused by the fact that in your expression

```
"^[0-9.><%,-(NULL)]*$"
```

the hyphen is considered to denote this character range: **`,-(`**. Because the parenthesis precedes the comma, the character range is considered to be in reverse order.

To represent a hyphen (`-`) in a character set, you need to avoid it being interpreted as denoting a character range. This is most easily achieved by placing the dash at the beginning or the end of the character set.

Comment: The expression would also allow NULLNULLNULL. Perhaps move the asterix inside the first sub-expression?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I was under the impression that NULLNULLNULL would need to match. Actually, as per OP's original expression, it would.